# Does YouTube support Live ingest of HEVC over RTMP or is this only available via HLS?

Tags: youtube-livestreaming-api, hevc, h.265

On the site https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/2853702?ref_topic=6136989 only h.264 is listed as an avalible injest codec however on the page https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/guides/hls-ingestion it states that "Supported video codecs are H264 and HEVC."

I've experimented a bit but have been unable to get an RTMP connection with HEVC. When i switch back to h.264 and maintain all the same codec parameters it works fine.

I talked to the YouTube Chat support and he said:

"I've checked our available resources here and there is no information yet for hevc. Maybe you can check the site if they have support as well. https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/support"

So here I am :)

Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 3):

Short answer: HEVC is not supported by RTMP.

RTMP protocol supports H264 but does not support HEVC because it's underlying container FLV does not support HEVC. So unless Adobe specifies it in the specification, it is unlikely to be supported by anyone. The spec was defined quite a while ago when most modern codec was H264.

HLS protocol supports both H264 and HEVC. It is based on MPEG-TS or fMP4 which have the support of both these codecs.

You can hack / force put HEVC into FLV and then stream with RTMP (some people do it for their custom streaming pipeline or apps), but nobody except you could receive it since it would not conform to the specification.

Links:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_video_container_formats#Video_coding_formats_support
- https://www.adobe.com/devnet/rtmp.html
- https://www.adobe.com/devnet/f4v.html

Comment: YouTube says that HLS ingest has higher latency, is there an alternative protocol that supports HEVC and can be processed with low latency?

Answer (score 1):

After years, YOUTUBE support HEVC over RTMP，and OBS have support it.

Links：

- [obs-pull-request](https://github.com/obsproject/obs-studio/pull/8522)
- [enhance-rtmp-specs-v1](https://github.com/veovera/enhanced-rtmp/blob/main/enhanced-rtmp-v1.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

Some enthusiasts made changes in RTMP protocol to support HEVC. It came from streaming cameras side but looks like it's working with just minor changes.

Take a look at our approach to this: [Support for HEVC over RTMP in Softvelum products](https://blog.wmspanel.com/2019/05/support-hevc-rtmp-nimble-streamer-larix.html)